# how to attach to java process in eclipse without re-installing fresh app?

Tags: java, android

I want to debug my android widget.

Of course it can run without the app itself to run.

I want to debug something that happens in the android-service java code

without fresh installing the app.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you app is deployed and runs on a device and device is connected to your PC or Mac.

Open *"DDMS"* perspective -> Choose a device in *"Devices"* view  -> Select the process your app runs in -> Press *"Debug"* button (with a green bug) in "Devices" view. Now you can switch back to "Java" perspective and put a breakpoint to the place you want to debug. Breakpoint should become green, meaning Eclipse has attached to the process. Update your widget and debug the code.

Comment: the problem is that my widget crashes before I catch it. I try to set earlier breakpoint, but then the process isn't seen on the DDMS

Comment: Checkout Logcat for exceptions. Add more Log.d() output to find a place where widget fails to execute.